# PHP Date comparison with MySQL date field

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare the current date with a date field returned by a MySQL query called "expiry_date". This field is a date field formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` I'm using If Else, to initialize a variable with the result as follows:

```
$today = $expiry_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime("now"));
if ($row['expiry_date'] > $today)
{
    $msg="Not Expired";
}
else
{
    $msg="Expired";
}
```

This doesn't appear to work and I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: You're comparing d-M-Y to Y-m-d, per your own statement... also date defaults to the current time, so you're creating a string, converting it to a timestamp, then sending it to a function that defaults to that exact same timestamp.

Comment: "Does not appear to work" => it would help if you said *exactly how*.

Comment: compare strtotime($str1) and strtotime($str2) this should do it

Comment: since `$row` sounds like something of a database: If you can filter it on the database side, filter it on the database side (in the query). Correctly used, mysql beats any php application for matters of sorting, joining, filtering.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Ive corrected but still doesnt work.

Comment: By not working I mean, if I change expiry date to be an older date than today the $msg variable is not populated with "Expired" and visa versa.

Comment: OK, I've now tried:

$expiry_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($row['expiry_date']));
$today =  date("d-M-Y", strtotime("now"));  
if (strtotime($expiry_date) > strtotime($today)) 

No joy..

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = $expiry_date = new \Datetime();
$row_expiry_date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $row['expiry_date']);
if ($row_expiry_date > $today)
{
     $msg="Not Expired";
} else {
     $msg="Expired";
}
```

Comment: Hi ARMBouhali, now that I;ve implemented your suggestion correctly, it works. Many thanks for this.

Comment: @Taffman, Don't forget to accept the answer, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, you can either format the dates the same and compare as strings

```
$today = $expiry_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("now"));
if ($row['expiry_date'] < $today)
```

or you can convert the row data to a unix timestamp for the comparison.

```
$today = $expiry_date = time();
if (strtotime($row['expiry_date']) < $today)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `$today = $expiry_date =`  which should be `$today =` or  `$expiry_date =`

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

if (strtotime($row['expiry_date']) > $strtotime($today))
{
     echo "not expired";
} else {
    echo "expired";
}
```