# user login validation using logged date in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, authentication

I am creating a login page form online exam application using php. I have already created a login page successfully. I am maintaining a separate  table to trace user login details such as user name ,login date and etc. what I need is, if a user login to the page twice within a day, use needs to be  directed to another page like xxx.php. Is there any possibilities to get current date and validate it with login trace table details`enter code here`.

```
$today = getdate();
```

I hope that I can get the recent logged date using below query,

```
$qry_trace="
SELECT l_date FROM trace 
WHERE u_name='$session_username' 
order by l_date desc
";
$result_trace=mysql_query($qry_trace);
```

How can I validate current date and user's last login date.

Comment: So you know when the user did his last logon as per your SQL query. Are you are asking how you can compare that date with the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve it.

1. I assume that you are saving 'datetime' or 'timestamp' in the 'TRACE' table. Just storing the DATE will not be good
2. In PHP - date("Y-M-d", strtotime("now")); Will give you current Date in YYYY-MM-DD format
3. In MySQL - DATE('datetime_columnname') - Will give you DATE in YYYY-MM-DD format. Now you can do the comparison by doing the query and comparing with the PHP
4. Best way is to compare by using MySQL functionality itself, without comparing it again with PHP Date like

   `SELECT *, DATE(l_date) < DATE(NOW()) AS logged_today FROM trace WHERE u_name='$session_username' ORDER BY l_date DESC LIMIT 1`

You can even refer some of the following links:

- http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql
- [PHP Date comparison with MySQL date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112185/php-date-comparison-with-mysql-date-field)

Hope this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Only save the last login date in your database. If the user login again on the same date, the query will return a row in which case you can return to page xxx.php

### Trace Table structure would be like

| username | last_login_date |

Query would be like

```
$qry_trace="SELECT * FROM trace WHERE u_name='$session_username' AND last_login_date = "$today";
$result_trace=mysql_query($qry_trace);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_trace) > 0)
    // go to xxx.php
else 
    // normal login
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current timeStamp using [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
$current_time = time();
$before_24_hours = $current_time - (60 * 60 * 24);
```

And your query will be like following

```
$sql = "SELECT count(l_date) FROM trace WHERE u_name='$session_username' AND l_date < "'.$currentTime.'" AND l_date > "'.$before_24_hours.'"";
```

Note: first of all you need to log timeStamp rather than storing date.